# Lost my title page, author and date

Tags: titles, datetime

I remember when I did type in LaTex before it would give me a front page to the document which said Title and a date.. Now it just begins right from the document body itself. No Author, No date, No front Page, No title.

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in
   Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series}
\date{October 31, 475}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
    \and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\date{April 4,2013}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 Hello
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After `\begin{document}` insert `\maketitle`.

Comment: Note that that code *does* give you a title page. It gives you a title page with precisely the contents you have requested i.e. the single word 'Hello'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By way of demonstration, `\maketitle` behaves differently depending on the class the document uses. So...

## `book` class with `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in
   Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series}
\date{October 31, 475}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
    \and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\date{April 4,2013}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: title page]

`report` with `\maketitle` produces a similar result.

## `article` class with `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in
   Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series}
\date{October 31, 475}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
    \and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\date{April 4,2013}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: title runs into first page]

## `article` class with `titlepage`

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in
   Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series}
\date{October 31, 475}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
    \and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\date{April 4,2013}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
 \maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\maketitle` within the `titlepage` environment. This is because `titlepage` just gives you an empty page to design as you will. If you don't put anything in it, it is just an empty page.

[image: a title page again]

`book` class with `titlepage` produces similar output.

An easier way to achieve the same result given that you don't really want to customise the layout of the title would be to just use `\maketitle` with the `book` class (as above) or, in `article`, to use the `titlepage` option for the class:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\title{The Triangulation of Titling Data in
   Non-Linear Gaussian Fashion via $\rho$ Series}
\date{October 31, 475}
\author{John Doe\\ Magic Department, Richard Miles University
    \and Richard Row, \LaTeX\ Academy}
\date{April 4,2013}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```